# Direct link to form using freeform

Tags: plugin-freeform

We have a form on our website that helps us build subscribers organically. But, we'd like to be able to share a direct link to our subscribe form so that we can do direct outreach to gain subscribers. Does freeform allow you to access the form directly via a url?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no... but that kind of thing is not really Freeform's responsibility - Craft gives you the flexibility to output whatever you want wherever you want, but in order to do so you need to create templates and/or routing to suit your requirements.